# RegEx for removing empty lines using lookarounds

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

when target is start of context , this match will fail

```
let txt = `「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」

「哈，哈……」`;

console.dir(txt.match(/(?<=^[「『][^\n]+[』」])\n\n(?=[「『][^\n]+[』」]$)/gm));
```

but if add a newline at start, match will work

```
let txt = `
「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」

「哈，哈……」`;
```

anyone know which part of regex is wrong? or this is `(?<=)` limit?

anyway make this can match it by only one regex and still use `(?<=)`

---

my env is support `lookBehind`, and some of my other rule is need to check prev, so i hope can handle this question by `lookBehind` and `lookAhead`

---

one regex is mean, do not use 2 or more regexp for handle this

expmale

```
    [/(?<=^[「『][^\n]+[』」])\n\n(?=[「『][^\n]+[』」](?:\n|$))/, '\n'],

    [/(?<=^[「『][^\n]+[』」])\n\n(?=[「『][^\n]+[』」]$)/gm, '\n'],
```

---

code

```
let txt = `「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」

「哈，哈……」

「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」

「哈，哈……」`;

console.dir(txt.replace(/(?<=^[「『][^\n]+[』」])\n\n(?=[「『][^\n]+[』」]$)/gm, '\n'));
```

expected outout is

`「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」\n「哈，哈……」\n「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」\n「哈，哈……」`

real output is (in node.js 12)

`「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」\n\n「哈，哈……」\n「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」\n「哈，哈……」`

Comment: JavaScript (in the browser at-least) does not support look-behind `(?<=)`.

Comment: @DeanTaylor, `/(?<!\$)\d+/.exec('it’s worth about €90'); `, is it a lookbehind? It works, i think

Comment: My browser doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: `make this can match it by only one regex and still use (?<=)` Can anyone translate this, I can't figure out what it means ?

Comment: Yeah, not only is it a look behind assertion, but it is of _variable width_. As far as I know, only M$ Dot-Net engine can do that.

Comment: You can find the ECMAScript / JavaScript [Regex Lookbehind support matrix here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions) (scroll up a little bit after clicking link). It looks like there is some support in Node.js depending on the version you are running.

Comment: this can help check does your env is support or not https://github.com/bluelovers/regexp-support

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/29472

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the assertions, since they are single use.
You couldn't use them in a global context because you use both
anchors in them `^$`.

Therefore, they are useless.
To distinguish the line breaks, just add capture groups.
Also, don't use Unicode characters inside character classes, you may make a
mistake one day.

Just the way I would do it ...

`/^[\u300c\u300e][^\r\n]+[\u300f\u300d](\s*\r?\n\s*\r?\n\s*)[\u300c\u300e][^\r\n]+[\u300f\u300d]$/`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 [\u300c\u300e] 
 [^\r\n]+ 
 [\u300f\u300d] 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \s* 
      \r? \n \s* 
      \r? \n \s* 
 )                             # (1 end)
 [\u300c\u300e] 
 [^\r\n]+ 
 [\u300f\u300d] 
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if it'd be OK to remove the empty lines with some other expression, such as:

```
([「『][^\r\n]*[』」])\s*([「『][^\r\n]*[』」])
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /([「『][^\r\n]*[』」])\s*([「『][^\r\n]*[』」])/gm;
const str = `「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」

「哈，哈……」

「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」

「哈，哈……」

「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」
「哈，哈……」
「呀啊，居然能見到比自己還年輕的母親，時空穿梭真是恐怖呀」
「哈，哈……」`;

console.log(str.replace(regex, `$1\n$2`));
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GqKlRc/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/GqKlRc/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### [Demo with lookarounds](https://regex101.com/r/xLthK3/1/)

Comment: thx, but becuase some of my other regexp pattern is need use `lookBehind` so , so if can i hope can handle this by lookBehind

Comment: i use node.js, and it is support, so didn't need worry about this part